# Need advice for programming languages for a custom GUI

Tags: 14.04, gui, programming

I just transitioned from windows to Ubuntu and so far loving it. On my list of tasks is to develop a GUI interface for collecting data from a remote device through RS232, compile and display the results. Currently my plans are to make a simple logic analyzer to display waveforms and a customized data logger for displaying text data as well as a graphing the results.

I have experience on the embedded side with C/C++, assembler and some Java, plus good old basic. But unfortunately the PC side is total new to me and I’m getting overwhelmed with my research.

My questions are:
1) What is the native (loosely used) language for Linux for API development?
2) What is the best way to collect and buffer data from a RS232 device?

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally go with Java, since it's multiplatform and simpler than C++. You can use JavaFx for your GUI (Swing is also an option, but it seems that JavaFx is the official GUI framework now) and [java-simple-serial-connector](http://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/) for interfacing with the serial port.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Ubuntu SDK](https://askubuntu.com/tags/ubuntu-sdk/info), a plugin for Qt Creator. Qt Creator uses C++ and is the only to support developing for Ubuntu for phones and tablets. It is also easy to make a GUI, with or w/o C++ (you can write a pure [QML](https://askubuntu.com/tags/qml/info) application). It is also cross-platform, so you can build for Linux, Mac OS X and Windows.